# Responsive Design and Sticky div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a two column layout. If a certain screen size is met they break so that everything will be shown in one column. That is why the ordering of those elements is important to make sure that the proper elements are shown first when viewed with a smaller screen.

The issue with this set up is, that the second "to be made sticky" aside-element is not properly floating right, but instead some where in between.

see in action: http://jsfiddle.net/zn3qz/

```
       .main {
            width: 60%;
            margin-right: 5%;
            float: left;
        }
        aside {
            width: 35%;
            float: right;
        }    

    <section class="main">Header</section>
    <aside>picture</aside>
    <aside>to be made sticky</aside>
    <section class="main">List of things</section>
```

Comment: Why are there `<br />` tags in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi. Just to illustrate that the content varies in size (e.g. picture takes up more than one line). Otherwise it would seem like everything is aligned.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/zn3qz/1/ if you want responsive please use ref this site http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will take a look. I don't understand your eaxmple. The only difference is seciton .main instead of only .main? (in addition to the border of course). I did not think that would make a difference. But even in your jsfiddle it is still not a two column design but the second aside element is in between the main and the right bar.

Comment: now try this http://jsfiddle.net/zn3qz/3/

Comment: Thanks, Fags. But this will not work. The issue is that I need to have the HTML as indicated. Because of the responsive design. Later I want to show the items in the following order when viewed on a small device: header, picture, sticky, list of things

Comment: Your markup could be in a completely different order than you have posted and still get the desired order for smaller devices.

Comment: Thanks! if that is the case, it would be brilliant if you could hint how that would be done.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, here's another variation: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/TtT6h/

The only real change I've made is to the CSS where I've added

```
aside{  
clear:right;
}
```

This ensures that the second aside clears the first aside and can slide completely to the right.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I tried that as well. The only issue is then the gap between the header and the list of things section since it slides beneath the end of the picture aside element.

Comment: If you know the height of the header, here's a variation that may work well for you: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/yE5gw/

Answer (score 0):

For something like this jquery is very help full. You can get the window width and based on that width you can edit the css to make one column or two.